# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{7}} + \cdots +\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2 -n + 1}})$

Tags: real-analysis

I used the Limit Comparison Test with the Harmonic Series to prove that the series above is divergent. I'm
not sure how to calculate the limit, I found that the series is bounded between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ and I guess the limit is  probably $+\infty$ since all the terms are positive, I'm confused writing down the demonstration. I feel that I'm close, but I dont know how to put it on paper. What am I missing?

Comment: Except harmonic series terms go to $\infty$. This summation only goes up to $n$. And it does converge, since you can show that the limit satistifes $$\frac{1}{2}\leq L \leq 1$$ Your use of limit comparison test was invalid.

Comment: Can you find $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}\,?$$ Can you estimate the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using
$$ k-1<\sqrt{k^2-k+1}<k $$
one has
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{k^2-k+1}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k-1}.$$
Since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx=\ln2 $$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx=\ln2, $$
so one has
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{k^2-k+1}}=\ln2. $$